# Interpreting correlation coefficient after log transform

Tags: correlation, data-transformation, interpretation

I have a pair of variables X and Y that exhibit non-linear relationship. The relationship is linearised by applying log10 transform to both (checked using scatter plots). Untransformed variables have correlation close to 0, while for transformed data it goes up to 0.68. Question is how to interpret the correlation coefficient on the transformed data. For the untransformed data, it is relatively easy. But I am not sure how to explain correlation between transformed variables to a non-statistical audience.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Explaining this to a non-statistical audience should be relatively straightforward, since I would expect an informed lay audience to understand logarithms. My fear is that you actually mean a "non-mathematical" audience.

I would go about this two ways. First, I wouldn't present log-transformed values on a unit scale, I would present the untransformed values and use a logarithmic scale. That is, instead of plotting `log10(y)` versus `log10(x)` on unit axes, I would plot `y` versus `x` on logarithmic axes. I would be sure to point this out to the audience. Finally, I would explain the logarithmic scale as being linear in the multiplicative sense.

I've tried this on a number of non-mathematical audiences and they seem to understand my point.

Good luck.